# How to add filter logic in the Get records of a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to retrieve lead records if the email or userid matches. 
[image]

Now there is no way to add a filter logic for the OR condition. Based on some comments on this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lDvCQAU
the OR condition works if we use the same fields.

Does anyone have any workaround for getting the OR conditions on multiple fields to work on the flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. OR conditions don't work for multiple field. A workaround would be to use to 2 Get Record elements. One for UserId another for Email. After each Get Record use a Loop element to iterate over fetched records and add in a Record Collection Variable.
Flow would look something like this:

[image]
[image]

Record Collection Variable may contain duplicates which can be handled using Loop (to iterate over Get_By_UserId) and Decision (Add to Collection Variable if not already present).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a good workaround

Comment: Welcome. Please look out for the duplicates though.